# Move (Copy) value of a cell based on dropdown value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a basic CRM using Google Sheets that holds all the client's data in one sheet and shows which part of the deal stage they're in on another sheet. Below is an example of what I mean.

Sheet 1:

```
Name |  Email  |  Deal Stage |
Ian     ian@..  >>Pre-launch << dropdown list 
Ken     ken@..  >>Pre-launch << dropdown list 
Dan     dan@..  >>Out-Reach  << dropdown list
Ben     ben@..  >>Call Booked<< dropdown list
```

Sheet 2:

```
Pre-Launch | Out-Reach | Brochure Sent | Call Booked |
Ian          Dan                         Ben
Ken
```

I'm looking to create a script that fires `onEdit` of any item in the dropdown cells. Is this possible, and what's the cleanest way?

I have created this [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/180-4PE9y325xxSyWyxX1eRpE0P2QIiXtzZ0rLzDi-9g/edit?usp=sharing) which only includes the feature in question.

Answer (score 0):

One more try.

```
function dealStage(e)
{
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = e.source;
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('ClientData');
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  var clientheaders = rngA[0];
  var dsSht = ss.getSheetByName('DealStage');
  var dsShtRng = dsSht.getRange(2, 1, dsSht.getLastRow(), dsSht.getLastColumn());
  dsShtRng.clearContent();
  var dsShtHdrsRng = dsSht.getRange(1, 1, 1, dsSht.getLastColumn());
  var dsShtHdrsRngA = dsShtHdrsRng.getValues();
  var dsheaders = dsShtHdrsRngA[0];
  var prelaunch = [];
  var outreach = [];
  var brochuresent = [];
  var callbooked = [];
  var dsi = clientheaders.indexOf('Deal Stage');
  var ni = clientheaders.indexOf('Name');
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {

    var dsv = rngA[i][dsi];
    var nv = rngA[i][ni]
    if(dsv!='')
    {
        switch(dsv)
        {
          case('Pre-Launch'):
            prelaunch.push([nv]);
            break;
          case('Out-Reach'):
            outreach.push([nv]);
            break;
          case('Brochure-Sent'):
            brochuresent.push([nv]);
            break;
          case('Call-Booked'):
            callbooked.push([nv]);
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  var dsstartrow = dsSht.getLastRow()+1;
  for(var i=0;i<dsheaders.length;i++)
  {
    var hdr = dsheaders[i];
    switch(hdr)
    {
      case('Pre-Launch'):
        if(prelaunch.length>0)dsSht.getRange(dsstartrow,i+1,prelaunch.length,1).setValues(prelaunch);
        break;
      case('Out-Reach'):
        if(outreach.length>0)dsSht.getRange(dsstartrow,i+1,outreach.length,1).setValues(outreach);
        break;
      case('Brochure-Sent'):
        if(brochuresent.length>0)dsSht.getRange(dsstartrow,i+1,brochuresent.length,1).setValues(brochuresent);
        break;
      case('Call-Booked'):
        if(callbooked.length>0)dsSht.getRange(dsstartrow,i+1,callbooked.length,1).setValues(callbooked);
        break;
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

ClientData Sheet:

[image]

DealStage Sheet:

[image]

Validation Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Cooper. However, this solution only works if the `Deal Stage(s)` are set up as individual sheets. In this case, that won't work. I need to keep all the data in Sheet 1 and use Sheet 2 to represent which `Deal Stage` a person `Name` is in.